# submitting data to another site

Tags: php, jsp

I'd like some help in taking data input from a user, using that input to complete a form on a different site and then collecting the results that the site outputs. Would it be possible to do this via PHP? If it helps/ additional info, the target site is in JSP. 
The site in question is a result site for my university. It's done in JSP and there's no sort of API through which I can fetch the data. I'd like to be able to take user input ( unique student ID etc) , submit that to the result website, and fetch the results onto my own to do some calculations. Would it be possible to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well technically you can. if you create an http post request to that site you can send data to that site but the response will be the html code of the page. but as a security most of the sites usually protects their sites from such actions so they put a token inside their forms so that they can be able to know whether the form data is coming from their site or was submitted by external source.

you can try to send post HTTP using curl 
here is a sample tutorial

https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: I'm sure I can somehow filter the HTML content I receive into getting my required data. I just looked over the HTML source of the website and found that they have an inner link which has the format of a GET request, something like this : `url=url +"?registerno="+registerno+"&frmdate="+frmdate+"&iden=1"+"&vericode="+document.getElementById('txtvericode').value;`. Now I have to figure out a way to bypass their captcha , which seems to be a simple one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if the external site does not have APIs to provide the data. Normally cross-origin HTTP request would be disallowed for a web application. Read more about CORS [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).